# access APNS notifications in UIAutomation testing iOS

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I am working on UIAutomation testing for my iPad app. There are APNS notifications received when one user shares files with other user. I need to look at what notifications are there and then tap on those notifications. I have done lot of research on this but I am unable to succeed. Is there any way to implement it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can separate them by title property. 
Example:

```
UIATarget.onAlert = function onAlert(alert) {
    var title = alert.name();

    //check by title, which alert is.

    // test if your script should handle the alert, and if so, return true
    // otherwise, return false to use the default handler
    return false;
}
```